# pass an array in a function to string JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

I have the following problem with the following code:
When I pass the Array to "track" I always get an error, I think it may be because an object is being passed and a String, but I'm not sure and I can't check it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.twKeyword.length; i++){
    var stream = client.stream('statuses/filter', {track: data.twKeyword[i]});
    }
```

I have tried:

- data.twKeyword
- data.twKeyword[i]
- [data.twKeyword]
- `data.twKeyword`
- `data.twKeyword[i]`
- 'data.twKeyword[i]'
- data.twKeyword[0].value
- data.twKeywprd[0].toString()

And none of these options has given me a positive result.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Please who the entire relevant code, and the error you're getting

Comment: error really none but tells me undefined or directly tells me nothing

Comment: What is supposed to be passed to `track`?

Comment: @Joe take that word and find it on Twitter in srteaming

Answer (score 0):

He creado una variable nueva a la que le he ido pasando los valores del Array:

```
var x1 = JSON.stringify(data.twKeyword[i].name);
```

Después como estos valores se mostraban con doble comillas (""), he utilizado el siguiente código para eliminarlas:

```
x1.replace(/['"]+/g, '')
```

El código ha quedado así, y funciona:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.twKeyword.length; i++){
    var x1 = JSON.stringify(data.twKeyword[i].name);
    var stream = client.stream('statuses/filter', {track: x1.replace(/['"]+/g, '')});
}
```